# Get and manage dev lib packages for arm on x86 host?

Tags: apt, package-management, libraries, arm, cross-compilation

Is there a proper way to maintain packages for architectures other than the host? I need a bunch of libraries for a project I am porting to android, and I notice that all of them are available for both `armhf` and `arm64` in the ubuntu repos, but `apt-get` gives me only the files for the host architecture.

What I need to know is how to get and manage the packages on my system to avoid any conflicts between different architecture versions?

I'd appreciate newb friendly answers as I am a very casual Linux user, and I am not too well versed in the platform idioms and usage.

Edit: OK, I found out that I can do:

```
sudo apt-get install package:arch
```

however while that worked for i386 package on 64bit machine, when I try arm architectures I get a "unable to locate package". Other than that, the packages for different archs are installed in their own directories as far as the actual libraries are concerned, while include headers are duplicated, which shouldn't be a problem as they should be identical. But there is still the problem of installing the libraries for `armhf` and `arm64`.